# c#: sending files, mixed succeded files and corrupted files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, tcp, ip

I wrote that code after some research on the internet to send files throught computers at the same network. But, sometimes it's sending the files corrupted or with low quality (if the file is a picture). Can you check this out? 
*Note: I want to send only files with 10MB size.*

> **Server**

```
class Server
{
    IPEndPoint end;
    Socket sock;

    public Server()
    {
        end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
        sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        sock.Bind(end);
    }

    public static string path;
    public static string MsgCurrent = "Stopped";

    public void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            MsgCurrent = "Starting...";
            sock.Listen(100);
            MsgCurrent = "Works and looks for files";
            Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();
            byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 10]; //count per byte
            int receivedByteLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);
            MsgCurrent = "Receiving file ...";
            int fNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
            string fName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fNameLen);
            BinaryWriter write = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path + "/" + fName, FileMode.Append));
            write.Write(clientData, 4 + fNameLen, receivedByteLen - 4 - fNameLen);
            MsgCurrent = "Saving file....";
            write.Close();
            clientSock.Close();
            MsgCurrent = "The file was received";
        }
        catch
        {
            MsgCurrent = "Error, the file was not received";
        }
    }
}
```

> **Client**

```
 class Client
{
    public static string ipsendf;//added
    public static string MsgCurrent = "Idle";
    public static void SendFile(string fName)
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipsendf); //127.0.0.1 in "" as string
            IPEndPoint end = new IPEndPoint(ip, 5656);
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

            string path = "";
            fName = fName.Replace("\\", "/");
            while (fName.IndexOf("/") > -1)
            {
                path += fName.Substring(0, fName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
                fName = fName.Substring(fName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
            }
            byte[] fNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fName);
            if (fNameByte.Length > 10 * 1024 * 1024) //count per byte
            {
                //MsgCurrent = "File is greater than 850 kb";
                MsgCurrent = "File is greater than 10MB";
                return;
            }
            MsgCurrent = "Buffering...";
            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(path + fName);
            byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
            byte[] fNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fNameByte.Length);
            fNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fNameByte.Length);
            MsgCurrent = "Connecting to server ...";
            sock.Connect(end);
            MsgCurrent = "File sending ...";
            sock.Send(clientData);

            MsgCurrent = "Disconnecting...";
            sock.Close();
            MsgCurrent = "The file was sent ..";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default receive size for a socket is 8,192 bytes ([for reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). So from your code it looks like on the server, you're only reading the first 8,192 bytes of the message.

You can either increase that buffer size to match the size of the 10MB `clientData` buffer you allocate, for example, some where after `.Accept()` and before `Receive()`..

```
clientSock.ReceiveBufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
```

Or, receive in chunks by checking if there's anything left to read and keep filling up your local buffer. You'll probably get away with the potenitally massive message on a local network though, generally speaking in chunks would be the normal way to do it.

Also, you're using `FileMode.Append` in the write of the file in server, whereas I would have thought you want `FileMode.Create`. Otherwise, if you send the same file twice you'll get a 20MB file instead of a 10MB one.

Comment: this does not fixed the problem, any other suggestion? I believe that there is a problem with the client, because sometimes it can send the whole file without any interrupt. But, I am not so sure yet and I can't find the problem..

Comment: ex. I send an mp3 for about 8MB size. The first time sent only the first 500KB. When I close and reopen the client, I tried again to send the file, that was successful at 8MB.